# SUM 3 cells in a range, which are numeric

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am experimenting with the excel functions. 
I am trying to obtain the sum of a range of cells (A3:F3). 
However, I only want the first three months that are numeric from the last month. So given the table below.

1|  -----   A       --------------      B   --------------        C------------           D    -------------       E  ------------         F
2| 01/01/2015 | 01/02/2015 | 01/03/2015 | 01/04/2015 | 01/05/2015 | 01/06/2015
3|   --- 200    -----------  150    ------------       100  ------------   No       ----------   10      ------------    No

I would expect the output to be 260. 
Essentially I want to count three cells in a range if "<>No"
I understand that I would require the following functions.

```
=SUMIF()
=COUNT()
=ISNUMBER()
```

But I'm not sure what the ordering of this would be.
Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: The answer you picked doesn't actually do what you outlined. Plugging it in gives me 110, not 260.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula needs to be entered as an Array Formula (Press CTRL+ALT+SHIFT). The data you displayed would be found in the range A1:F2.

```
=SUM(IF(A1:F1>=LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER(A2:F2),A1:F1),3),A2:F2))
```

I get the 260 this way.

Comment: That's perfect, I have tried it with the No's in different places and it works for all situations. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

### Update 1

(hopefully with correct understanding of the question)
`=SUM(INDIRECT("R2C"&LARGE(ISNUMBER(A2:F2)*COLUMN(A2:F2),3)&":R2C6",FALSE))` - this is an array formula, you need to finish it by pressing CTRL+ALT+ENTER.

Original answer (summarizing data from last three month regardless how many of them contains numbers.
Excel will ignore non numeric values, so don't worry about "No". To take into account only last three month (compared to today): `=sumifs(A3:F3,A2:F2,">="&edate(today(),-3),A2:F2,"<="&today())`

Comment: This answer doesn't give you 260. I get 110 using this.

Comment: Good solution. However, despite me changing the formula from today() to the start date in range  --------   =sumifs(A3:F3,A2:F2,">="&edate(F2,-3),A2:F2,"<="&F2())      --------- The solution only obtains 110.

Comment: @AMorton1989: I've updated the formula, I hope it will work well now.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I still don't get the 260 using the new formula. I think the problem is that your formula doesn't first check which cells contain text. Take a look at my solution, maybe stepping through that helps to explain what I'm trying to say.

Comment: @rohrl77: your solution works too, but on my pc also mine is ok. Do you have other result, or error?

Comment: @MátéJuhász Ok. Odd. I must have made a mistake before. I reentered your version and it also works. Sorry, about that. +1 for you :- )